# Changing Google Maps polyline color only changes a part of the polyline of alternative routes

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, polyline, google-directions-api

When a user selects two locations, I'm trying to show one main route and two alternative routes. The main one's in blue and the other two are in gray. It works as expected.

I want to change the color of an alternative route to blue when the user taps on it. But only a part of it changes and the parts that belong to the main route remain gray. I need the whole length of the alternative route to turn blue.

Here's how it looks now:

**Main route**
[image: Main route]

**Alternative route 1**
[image: Alternative route 1]

**Alternative route 2**
[image: Alternative route 2]

It looks like the alternative routes overlap the main route so I already tried removing all polylines and re-adding them but it doesn't work. I also tried `setTag()` on polylines to distinguish them and change color but the `polyline` object returned from the `onClickListener` always have a null value for some reason.

Here's my code:

```
mMap.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPolylineClick(@NonNull Polyline polyline) {
                selectRoute(polyline);
            }
        });
```

```
private void selectRoute(Polyline selectedPolyline) {
        for (Polyline polyline : polylineList)
            polyline.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        selectedPolyline.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    }
```

```
private Polyline addPolyline(int position, boolean isMain) {
        List<Leg> altLegList = routeList.get(position).getLegList();
        ArrayList<LatLng> directionPositionsList = altLegList.get(0).getDirectionPoint();
        PolylineOptions polylineOptions = DirectionConverter.createPolyline(context, directionPositionsList, 8, isMain ? Color.BLUE : Color.GRAY);
        Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
        polylineList.add(polyline);

        return polyline;
    }
```

I use [this](https://github.com/akexorcist/GoogleDirectionLibrary) library to get the polylines using the following code:

```
GoogleDirection.withServerKey(BuildConfig.MAPS_API_KEY)
                    .from(startMarker.getPosition())
                    .to(destMarker.getPosition())
                    .transportMode(TransportMode.DRIVING)
                    .alternativeRoute(isShowingAltRoutes)
                    .execute(new DirectionCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDirectionSuccess(@Nullable Direction direction) {
                            //show three polylines, the first (main) in blue.
                            routeList = direction.getRouteList();

                            //show two alt routes
                            if (routeList.size() > 1)
                                for (int r = 1; r < 3; r++)
                                    addPolyline(r, false);

                            //add main route ON TOP of the alts
                            selectRoute(addPolyline(0, true));
                        }
                    });
```

I've been trying for a workaround for three days with no luck. Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong or a different way around this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Setting the Z-index of the selected route to a higher value and the others' to a lower value works.

```
for (Polyline polyline : polylineList) {
    polyline.setZIndex(0);
    polyline.setColor(Color.GRAY);
}
selectedPolyline.setZIndex(1);
selectedPolyline.setColor(Color.BLUE);
```